# Reliability of 100% height image + maintaining ratio with CSS

Tags: css

Is this CSS for sizing an `<img>` to 100% height and maintaining the ratio reliable (cross-browser)?

```css
#reel img
{
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

It seems to work on what browsers I have, but I'm sceptical of the `auto` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes. That's how you do it. Not sure what more to add. Edit: You could add `!important` to the auto-rule just in case the `img` has an inline `width` attribute. Edit2: Actually the `!important` doesn't seem necessary: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7ME8/

Comment: Thanks, just didn't want to end up finding out that a large chunk of browsers render the width weird.

Comment: I understand. They shouldn't though.